# Wifi stopped working: Init ucode -5 [Intel Wireless 9560]

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver, wireless-card

I once cold booted my laptop and the wifi stopped working completely. This is the error I get from dmesg when I filter for wireless driver info only.

### **Relevant specs:**

- **Operating System:** Ubuntu
- **Description:** Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS focal
- **PC make:** Dell Inspiron 7586 2-in-1
- **Linux Firmware:** linux-firmware/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1.187.4 all [installed]
- **Linux Headers:** 5.4.0-42-generic

```
$dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    8.050151] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.073632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.073635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    8.073898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.133208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9460, REV=0x318
[    8.156288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.159789] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    8.164794] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    8.164799] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    8.164816] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    8.164822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x98402404 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    8.164825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x34504D88 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    8.164828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x65A63677 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    8.164831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x015660A5 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    8.164834] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x39BEFAFE | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    8.164837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC1B9DFF0 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    8.164841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00409810 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    8.164844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFEE77FF | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    8.164847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.164882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.164951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    8.165020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    8.165247] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    8.165251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    8.165253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    8.411263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    8.424358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

**My wireless network adapter is recognized by the OS.**

```
name@name:~$ lspci
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)

name@name:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

name@name:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for name: 
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:a121c000-a121ffff
```

**Resolutions attempted:**

- Downloading official iwlwifi drivers from Intel, Dell and my /lib/firmware folder (-34.ucode from Intel and Dell and also the -33, -34, -38, -41, -43 and -46.ucode from /lib/firmware)
- Downloading the backport iwlwifi drivers from PPA

**Research:** My suspicion is that there might be a conflict with the Bluetooth module (hindering the correct firmware from being loaded) as there was a time the wifi briefly worked then stopped when I turned off Bluetooth. However, now I can't turn off Bluetooth and wifi. As you can see, the radio kill button has just the Bluetooth option which doesn't even work.

Does anyone know of a resolution?

Comment: Had a similar issue on v. 20.04  and found Airplane Mode had somehow turned on. Hope it's that simple.

Comment: I can confirm that my airplane mode is off. When I turn the airplane mode off, all connections are disabled and turn grey but when on, only the Bluetooth option appears. However, if I try turning the Bluetooth on, it also does not work and the Wi-Fi option is not present.